# php question - trying to add to an array if the key is not found

Tags: php, arrays, key

I've been going back and forth with in_array and for loops, but haven't quite been able to accomplish what I've been trying to do...

I have an array (named $contacts) that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [3] => 1
    [5] => 1
    [7] => 1
)
```

I'm trying to add additional key => value pairs based on results from a query:

```
//query results
+------+------+
| uid  | nid  |
+------+------+
|    1 |   24 |
|    3 |   23 |
|    4 |   22 |
|    5 |   28 |
|    6 |   29 |
|    7 |   30 |
|    8 |   27 |
+------+------+
```

What I'm trying to do is *if* the uid is *not* in the $contacts array keys, then I want to add it with a value of "0", so that the end result is this:

```
Array
(
    [3] => 1
    [5] => 1
    [7] => 1
    [1] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [6] => 0
    [8] => 0
)
```

Maybe I've been at this too long, because it seems really hard to do this, so hopefully, after stepping back and getting some help from someone here, I'll feel normal again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try something like:

```
if (!isset($contacts[1]))
    $contacts[1] = 0;
```

Comment: No, but I did figure it out...  I finally found the array_key_exists function, and now I got what I needed... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This?

```
foreach($results as $obj) {
   $contacts[] = (int) array_key_exists($obj['uid'], $contacts);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a php 5.3 method

```
$ar1 = array (
    3 => 1,
    5 => 1,
    7 => 1
);

$q = array(
    1 => 24,
    3 => 23,
    4 => 22,
    5 => 28,
    6 => 29,
    7 => 30,
    8 => 27
);

print_r( $ar1 + array_map( function($v){ return $v=0; }, $q ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
foreach ($result as $uid => $res) {
if (!array_key_exists($uid, $contacts)) {
    $contacts[$uid] = 0;
 }
}
```